# Could not load file or assembly... System cannot find the file specified c#

Tags: c#, reference

I use Word.Interop reference in my solution and have no errors or warnings.
When I run the program I get this message

[image]

I have already checked in the reference properties and "Embed Interop types" property is set to false.

I found that the marked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479803/c-sharp-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-cannot-find-file-specified) helped the questioner to solve a similar problem but I DO NOT understand what I should do.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you add the reference (meaning as a GAC reference or a file reference)?

Comment: Have you tried setting `Embed Interop types` to true?

Comment: reply 1: via GAC. reply 2: one project. reply 3: I'll try it even I saw a few answers to set to false

Comment: Duplicate?: [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8092201/456814).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem following the accepted answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies):

Use [FuseLogVw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to keep track of where your program is breaking and how it is breaking. This application has a table with lots of traces. Find out where the fault application is called and see what is wrong with it.